# Difference between Esper and Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-storm

My goal is to make a distributed application with publishers and consumers where i use CEP to process streams of data to generate event notifications to event consumers.

Whats the difference between Esper and Apache Storm?

Can I achieve what Storm does with only Esper, and when should I consider integrating Esper with Storm?

Im confused, I thought Esper provided the same functionality.

Comment: There is an Esper integration for Storm. You might also want to consider using Apache Flink: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/libs/cep.html

Comment: Im too deep into Esper atm so point of no return :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storm is a distributed realtime computation system which generally can be used for any purpose while Esper is an [Event Stream Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_stream_processing) and and event correlation engine (Complex Event Processing), therefore Esper is more specific.
Here are some use cases of them:

- Storm can be used to real-time consume data from Twitter and calculate to find the most used hashtag per topic.
- Esper can be used to detect event like: a normal train has speed 100 miles per hour and its speed is reported secondly. If the speed of the train increase to 130 miles per hour in 10 minutes, an event will be generated and notify train operator.

There are some more criteria you can consider when select between them:

- Storm is built-in designed for distributed processing while Esper seems not (My team evaluated 2016)
- Open source license (Storm) vs Commercial license (Esper)

Comment: But with Esper I can communicate using its adpater interface. I can send Events from one server to another using sockets or http with Espers api. I can also notify subscribers using only Esper. This is where im confused to why I should use Esper with Storm and kafka for instance. At least to me it seems I can achieve just this purely with Esper. I might be wrong, thats why I ask.

Comment: Yes, because you intented to use CEP for your stream processing, Esper is suitable. The point I wanted to mention is Storm is used for general purpose while Esper is more specific and we can use Kafa, Storm to achieve the same with Esper however requires more effort. Moreover, there are some use cases Storm can achieve but not Esper. So, depend on the purpose of project to choose

Answer (score 2):

Storm provides abstractions to run pieces of code and provides value is managing the distribution aspect such as workers, management, restart. Whatever piece of code you plug in is your job to code and your code must worry how and where it keeps state such as counts or other derived information. Storm is often used for extract-transform-load or ingest of streams into some store.

Esper provides abstractions for detecting situations among sequences of events by providing an "Event Processing Language (EPL)" that conforms to SQL92. Its an expressive, concise and extensible means to detect stuff without writing any or very little code. EPL can be dynamically injected and managed so you can achieve adding and removing rules at runtime without restarts. If you were to do this with code you would always have to restart the JVM/workers/topology.

Esper has horizontal scalability by integrating directly with Kafka Streams. But the code for this is not open source, currently.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, storm can offer a good management of resources, like load balancing, auto restart when machine down, a easier way to add machines or tasks, etc, which you have to handle it yourself if just using esper.